# Как получить доступ к полям dataset'a?

Tags: c#, winforms

Изучаю `c#`. Пока еще не все понимаю, поймите ребята. :)

Подскажите, аналог кода доступа к значению `fields` набора данных, например, в `Delphi` можно было просто так :

```
Query.FieldByName('id').AsInteger
```

Как это сделать в `c#`? (эти поля в `DataGrid` - е не вывожу, только в запросе есть)

*UPD:* `WinForms`, `MySqlClient`.

Comment: это wpf???

Comment: нет, winForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может это Вам поможет?

```
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Rows[rowIndex].ItemArray[index]//доступ для конкретной строки
    dataTable.Rows[rowIndex][/*columnIndex*/|/*columnName*/|/*column*/]
    foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)//итератор для строк
    {
        var columnValue = row.ItemArray[index];//по индексу
        var columnValue = row[/*columnIndex*/ | /*columnName*/ | /*column*/];//по индексу или имени колонки или объекту колонки
    }
```

Comment: Присоединяюсь - пример рабочий, сам на подобии делал.
Грубо говоря, нужно указать нужную строку и номер нужной колонки.

Comment: а если мне надо получить значение  1 поле ? без foreach - a.

Comment: foreach тут для строк...